# unable to send request from emulater to WCF

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I am coding a login page with Titanium framework and using Android simulator.
I need to authenticate user. I am using below mentioned code, but i get "Error" alert.

```
var loginWindow = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
            backgroundColor: '#CCD0D3',
            title: L('Login'),
            fullscreen: false,
            activity : {
                onCreateOptionsMenu : function(e) {
                    var menu = e.menu;
                    var cancel = menu.add({ title : L('Cancel') });
                    cancel.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                        var alertDialog = Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({
                            title: 'Clicked',
                            message: 'Cancel was clicked',
                            buttonNames: ['OK']
                        });
                        alertDialog.show();
                    });

                    var login = menu.add({ title : L('Login') });

                    login.addEventListener('click',function(e)
                    {
                        alert("Click");
                        if (txtUsername.value != '' && txtPassword.value != '')
                        {
                            var loginReq = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
                            loginReq.onreadystatechange = function(){
                                alert('onreadystatechange');
                            };
                            loginReq.onload = function()
                            {
                                alert("load");
                                var json = this.responseText;
                                var response = JSON.parse(json);
                                if (response.logged == true)
                                {
                                    alert("Welcome " + response.name + ". Your email is: " + response.email);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    alert(response.message);
                                }
                            };
                            loginReq.onerror = function(){
                                alert("Error");
                            };
                            loginReq.open("GET","http://localhost/iMessage/Authenticate.svc/CheckLogin/praveen/matoria");
                            // var params = {
                                // username: txtUsername.value,
                                // password: Ti.Utils.md5HexDigest(txtPassword.value)
                            // };
                            //loginReq.send(params);


                            loginReq.send(null);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert("Username/Password are required");
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            exitOnClose:true
        });
```

If i use browser and send the same request than it sends me following response:

```
{"email":"myEmail@gmail.com","logged":true,"name":"Praveen Matoria"}
```

FYI: For reference i am using following [link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/appcelerator/titanium-user-authentication/):

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have heard of issues before using localhost on an android emulator.

Comment: @Brian-Huenefeld : I shall try to consume online WCF in that case and test. Thanks for comment.

Comment: @Brain Huenefeld : after passing e argument to error function, i now have the exact error. It says "Connection to http://localhost refused". Probabily, either i should test with iPhone simulator or go with online WCF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the way finally to use localhost for android.
it clicked to my brains when i was accessing my virtual machine.

Solution: Every machine has atleast 3 IP addresses:

1. localhost
2. 127.0.0.1
3. Some internet IP addres through which you access internet. Go to command prompt and type "ipconfig". In my case, 192.168.1.6 was the IP address.

Use this and your requests would go to router first and than come back and forth.

May be i am wrong at some facts, but overall idea is same.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
loginReq.onerror = function(){
    alert("Error");
}
```

to

```
loginReq.onerror = function(e){
    alert("Error: " + e.error);
}
```

That should at least give you more information on the error that you're getting.

Comment: I shall test it at night, if not now. Shall mark it answer even if this let me know the error and i could resolve it. Thanks anyway.